# How to Prevent VS Code from Opening Library Files Instead of My Own during Flutter Exceptions?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I've been encountering frustration when dealing with VS code and Flutter errors as I find it unnecessary to open the library file each time instead of my own file. In my case, I attempted to log errors into the terminal using the following code:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  final logger = Logger();

  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    logger.e(details.exception, stackTrace: details.stack);
  };

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
  
}
```

However, to stop VS Code from showing the file each time, I had to untick the breakpoint as shown in the image:

[image: untick the break point image]

While this prevents the file from being paused, it doesn't fully resolve the issue; there might be potential risks or dangers associated with this approach that I am not aware of.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this in vscode?

Answer (score 0):

To debug only your project code (not the packages) switch this (image below) to "Debug my code" in your vscode statusbar while running the app. so the errors and breakpoints not paused in library/package.

[image: vscode debug my code]

Hopefully it can solve your problem